# C#: Implement an Interface witha Property of Any Type

Tags: c#, interface

I'm trying to implement an interface that requires a single property, but I don't explicitly care what type it is.  For example:

```
public interface IName
{
    dynamic Name {get; set;}
}
```

Then if I have a class I'd like to implement the IName interface with a type of string:

```
public class Person : IName
{
     public string Name {get; set;}
}
```

This however raises an error.  I know I could make the interface IName take a generic arguement `IName<T>` but that forces me to create a bunch of overloaded functions that take `IName<string>`, `IName<NameObj>`, `IName<etc>` instead of casting within a single function.

How can I require that a class contains a property?

Comment: Does the return type really need to be "any object"?  What will the consuming code look like, and how will it deal with literally *any* object being returned?  The only things you'll really know exist are methods on `Object`, and if you're going to use those, you might as well make the return type `Object`.  I guess if this is throw-away or internal code that you plan to reuse very little, then it might be okay.  Beyond this, I suggest taking advantage of the type system.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am unable to test this now, but maybe you could implement the interface explicitly.

```
public class Person : IName
{
    public string Name {get; set;}

    dynamic IName.Name {
        get { return this.Name; }
        set { this.Name = value as string; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Well Played.  This totally works.  Never would of thought of this.

Answer (score 13):

```
interface IName<T>
{
    T Name { get; set; }
}

class Person : IName<string>
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Best way to do this. dynamics should be best avoided, unless you are totaly sure what are you doing. And in many cases, you are not.

Answer (score 1):

Returning a dynamic allows you to return any type you please. Simply declare the type in your implementing class to be dynamic.

```
    public interface IName
    {
        dynamic name { get; set; }
    }

    public class Person: IName
    {
        private string _name;
        public dynamic name { get { return _name; } set { _name = value;} }
    }
```

edit:

note that you'll have to be careful about what you pass to name since the type of value will only be checked at runtime (the joys of using dynamic types).

```
Person p = new Person();
p.name = "me"; // compiles and runs fine, "me" is a string
p.name = p; // compiles fine, but will run into problems at runtime because p is not a string
```

Answer (score 0):

Make

```
public string Name {get; set;}
```

and make the return type Object.

Comment: Nope: `'Person' does not implement interface member 'IName.Name'. 'Person.Name' cannot implement 'IName.Name' because it does not have the matching return type of 'dynamic'.`  My code in the question was wrong though.  Good catch and updated.